# Given a list of strings and word S. Check if S exists in the list or not

Tags: c++

/*
What is the error in this code ? I always get false(0) even if the 
string is included in the list. Is the logic served correct for the above question ?
*/

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool ispresent(char (*stringlist)[100] , char *arr){
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 7 ; i++){
         if (stringlist[i] == arr){
             return true;
         }
    }
    return false;
}

int main(){
//given  a list of strings
char stringlist[7][100] ={ 

    "He",
    "is",
    "very",
    "bad",
    "instead",
    "do",
    "yourself"
};

//input word to check
char arr[50];
cin.getline(arr , 50 , '\n');

//check if word is present or not
bool found = ispresent(stringlist , arr) ;
cout << found;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `strcmp` or `std::string`, you are comparing pointers right now

Comment: Better yet, [use actual C++](http://ideone.com/DviRFq), not `C` code.  As to your logic, there is nothing wrong with the logic -- it fits quite well *if you use the C++ idioms*, and leave `C` alone.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the string comparison functions instead of ==. It doesn't work on strings. Example:

```
 strcmp(stringlist[i], arr)
```

And include the library string.h
The comparison operator works on primitive variables not on pointers. When using pointers that represent other type of data, you should implement your own methods/functions (or use methods/functions provided by libraries) as the == operator only compares the references, not what they reference.

Answer (score 0):

> if (stringlist[i] == arr)

The reason you always get false is because you are using the == operator which will always compare one element of the c-string instead of an entire part of the string. `string::find()` is what does the job.

You should use std::string where possible so you don't have to allocate/deallocate memory. In std::string there is the `str.find(str1)` function which gives out the first index where str1 was found in str. You can use that in this fashion

Information about `string::npos`: 
From [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/npos/):

> static const size_t npos = -1; 
>   Maximum value for size_t
>
> This value, when used as the value for a len (or sublen) parameter in 
>   string's member functions, means "until the end of the string".
>
> As a return value, it is usually used to indicate no matches.
>
> This constant is defined with a value of -1, which because size_t is an >unsigned integral type, it is the largest possible representable value for >this type.

This should work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// str is the string array
// str_size is the size of the array passed to the funcion
// str 1 is the string you are looking for.

bool ispresent(std::string str[], int str_size, std::string str1);

int main()
{
    const int SIZE = 4;
    std::string str0[SIZE];

    std::cout << "Enter four strings:\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        std::cin >> (str0)[i];

    std::string search_term;

    std::cout << "Enter a search term:";

    std::cin >> search_term;

    bool result = ispresent(str0, SIZE, search_term);

    // If output is 1 then it was found
    std::cout << result;

    return 0;
}

bool ispresent(std::string str[], int str_size, std::string str1)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < str_size; i++)
    {
        // Use the find function in string on each element of the array.
        if (str[i].find(str1) != std::string::npos)
            return true;    // Return true if found
    }

    // String not found
    return false;
}
```